# Extract MAC address from a string

Tags: c#

I have a string like this : `00:1E:AE:4F:20:0BDntl3l`

I want to extract the mac address that is `00:1E:AE:4F:20:0B` from the string using a regex and discard the `Dntl3l`. How can I achieve this in c# ?

I have tried the below code, but its still returning me the same string.

```
    string s = "00:1E:AE:4F:20:0BDntl3l";
    var regex = "^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$";
    var newformat = Regex.Match(s, regex);
    Console.WriteLine(newformat);
```

Comment: It won't match because of the $, which means match to end of string. You can either drop that, or write a regex to cover the remaining bits (any alphanumeric?) and put that before the dollar. Or just e.g. cut the string at 17 characters?

Comment: Remove `$` from the pattern: `var regex = "^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})";`

Comment: Would it be an option to just `.Substring` the string?

Comment: And besides removing the trailing `$`sign, you could also remove the leading `^` just in case that your MAC containing string can also have some characters preceding the MAC.

Comment: How about just `"00:1E:AE:4F:20:0BDntl3l".Substring(0, 17)`?

Answer (score 7):

The following worked for me:

```
var s = "DSz00:1E:AE:4F:20:0BDntl3l";

var macRegex = "([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:){5}[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}";
var result = Regex.Match(s, macRegex);

Console.WriteLine(result); // 00:1E:AE:4F:20:0B
```

But I personally find this a bit confusing, so I would do something like this instead:

```
var s = "DSz00:1E:AE:4F:20:0BDntl3l";

var hexPair = "[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}";
var macRegex = $"{hexPair}:{hexPair}:{hexPair}:{hexPair}:{hexPair}:{hexPair}";
var result = Regex.Match(s, macRegex);

Console.WriteLine(result); // 00:1E:AE:4F:20:0B
```

Edit: Or, if you combine the two:

```
var s = "DSz00:1E:AE:4F:20:0BDntl3l";

var hexPair = "[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}";
var macRegex = $"({hexPair}:){{5}}{hexPair}";
var result = Regex.Match(s, macRegex);

Console.WriteLine(result); // 00:1E:AE:4F:20:0B
```

Edit 2: Yet another one I came up with using `Enumerable.Repeat` from LINQ and `String.Join()`, although I think this is an overkill :

```
var s = "DSz00:1E:AE:4F:20:0BDntl3l";    

// Make an IEnumerable of 6 hex pair regexes
var sixHexPairs = Enumerable.Repeat("[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}", 6);

// And join them with a ":"
var macRegex = string.Join(":", sixHexPairs);
var result = Regex.Match(s, macRegex);

Console.WriteLine(result); // 00:1E:AE:4F:20:0B
```